# bigquery nested object : No such field

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with this schema : [image]

I'm trying to upload some data from Google Coud Storage using the python client. The file is JSON newline delimited. Most of my lines don't have the field "passenger_origin.accuracy" but when the filed is present I have the following error :

> Error while reading
> data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position
> 2122510: No such field: driver_origin.accuracy. (error code: invalid)
>
> Error while reading
> data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position
> 2126317: No such field: passenger_origin.accuracy. (error code:
> invalid)

Example of an invalid row :

```
{
    "id": 1479443,
    "is_obsolete": 0,
    "seat_count": 1,
    "is_ticket_checked": 0,
    "score": 0.3709318902,
    "is_multimodal": 0,
    "fake_paths": 0,
    "passenger_origin": {
        "id": 2204,
        "poi_uuid": "15b4e52c-7c58-442c-98df-1eb06079f6bb",
        "user_id": 1987,
        "accuracy": 250.0,
        "disabled": 0,
        "last_update": "2017-03-10T15:15:39",
        "created": "2016-02-05T17:06:26",
        "modified_by_user": 1,
        "is_recurrent": 0,
        "source": 1,
        "hidden_by_user": 0,
        "kind": 2,
    },
    "driver_origin": {
        "id": 412491,
        "poi_uuid": "47e90b6d-e178-4e02-9f02-f4ea5f8beaa1",
        "user_id": 71471,
        "disabled": 0,
        "last_update": "2017-11-02T10:09:09",
        "created": "2017-11-02T10:09:09",
        "modified_by_user": 0,
        "is_recurrent": 0,
        "source": 1,
        "hidden_by_user": 0,
        "kind": 2,
    },
    "passenger_destination": {
        "id": 2203,
        "poi_uuid": "c531c3ca-47f0-4003-8098-1272fee8d018",
        "user_id": 1987,
        "accuracy": 250.0,
        "disabled": 0,
        "last_update": "2017-03-10T15:12:42",
        "created": "2016-02-05T17:06:19",
        "modified_by_user": 1,
        "is_recurrent": 0,
        "source": 1,
        "hidden_by_user": 0,
        "kind": 1,
    }
}
```

The table is created before the upload of the data and is not modified since. I don't understand why the upload is failing on theses fields ? Do the RECORD fields have to be REPEATED ?

Answer (score 3):

To ignore the fields that aren't present in the schema, use a combination of:

- [`configuration.load.ignoreUnknownValues`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.ignoreUnknownValues)
- [`configuration.load.maxBadRecords`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.maxBadRecords)

Setting the first to `true` and the second to some arbitrarily-high number, e.g. `100000`, will enable the load to succeed even if there are extra fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in my case the fields are presents in the schema even though the error says the contrary. 
Most of my entries don't have the field `driver_origin.accuracy` or `passenger_origin.accuracy` but when the error occurs when they are present

Comment: where are these configs set

Answer (score 0):

The problem was configuration.load.autodetect was set to True. I set it to False and the problem was fix